# Get name of factory from within factory "type inflection"?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, factory

How would I get the name of the factory from within it?

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('SomeApp.Resources').factory('WidgetFactory',

        ['$resource', 'settings',function($resource,settings ) {

             console.log(/*my factory name*/ );
        }
    ]);
}());
```

I looked up all the methods on the provide $get but all I see is the injected $resource. I guess I could 'var' the name and use that in both places, but as a curiosity it would be nifty to know how to get to the definition name.

Use case might be load a config to see what version of an api to use based on $resource name.

Comment: `var`ing the name would make the most sense to me.

Comment: factory name within factory you can hard code it? why u need it?

Comment: Your downvote is unwarranted, as I clearly stated a use case. What if I wanted to automate the generation of resources factory js files? This would make it more clear/easy.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up **var** ing it.

```
var factoryName = "WidgetFactory";

    angular.module('SomeApp.Resources').factory(factoryName,['$resource','ResourceHelper', function($resource,ResourceHelper ) {    

            var version = ResourceHelper.getResourceVersion( factoryName );
            var Widget = $resource('http://localhost:8282/widget/' + version + "/", ...
```

*And voila!* We only have to hard-code it once.